# Using a Creative Live Chat Cam with Skype

Tags: macos, skype, webcam

I am trying to set up a Creative Live Chat Cam on a Mac mini to use with Skype. How do I get this combination to work?

Comment: The guide on [Ask] will help you refine your question by showing what you've tried and/or what exactly "you don't get". If you don't get a good answer, feel free to try editing in some details or links on what question you used and what step is failing or doesn't make sense. We love details here.

Answer (score 1):

Your Camera is a UVC -Universal Video Camera type.

In English that means you should just plug it in and it will work.

Following steps should do it:

Plug the camera in..

Open Skype

If Skype does not auto-identify the camera (asking you if you want to use it)

Go to the Skype Preferences

Go to the Audio Video

There you should be able to select the camera + Microphone + Speakers

You will see your self if all worked.